# Dynos not restarting during 24-hour cycling (python)

Tags: python, heroku

I am pretty new to python and I have a python script running detached as one-off dyno. 24 hours after the script is started, heroku cycles the dynos. The script exits; but does not restart. What am I missing here? I would like the script to be run automatically instead as a one-off dyno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku [one-off dynos never restart, by design](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#formation-dynos-vs-one-off-dynos).

Instead, create a [background worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) by specifying the relevant command to run in your [`procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) - once scaled, those will run continuously and be restarted.